# running Karma in a loop and programmatic access

Tags: karma-runner

It's a question more about the architecture of a program that runs karma in a CI pipeline.

I have a set of web components. They are using karma to run tests (following open-wc.org recommendations). Then I have my custom CI pipeline that allows to schedule a test of selected group of components.
When the test is scheduled it execute tests for each component one by one. However in my logs I am getting messages like

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. 12 exit listeners added to [process]. Use
>   emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

or sometimes

> listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:9877

which breaks the test (exists the process).

I can't really pinpoint the problem so I am guessing that I am not running the test in a correct way.

On the server I am using `Server` class to initialize the server, then I am calling `start` on the server. When the callback function passed to `Server` constructor is called I am assuming the server is stopped and I can start over with another component. But clearly it is not the case per errors I am getting.

So the question is what would be the right way of running Karma test in a loop, one by one, using node API instead of CLI.

### Update

To be specific of how I am running the tests.

I am:

1. Creating configuration by calling `config.parseConfig` where the argument is component's karma config file
2. Calling `new Server(opts, (code) => {})` where `opts` are the one generated in step 1
3. Adding listeners for `browser_complete` and `browser_error` to generate a report and to store it into the data store
4. Cleaning up (removing reference for the server) when constructor callback is called
5. Getting next component from the queue and going back to #1

Answer (score 0):

To answer my on question,
I have moved the whole logic of executing a single test to a child process and after the test finishes, but before the next test is run, I am making sure the child process is killed. No more error messages are showing up.